# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on string

Tags: php, string, mysqli, fetch, fatal-error

We are currently running into an issue when we try and get the username from a SQL database. This is our code for the query and the fetch_object()

```
<?php  

$user = 'root';
$password = 'root';
$db = 'collabowrite';
$host = 'localhost';
$port = 3306;
$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $db);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
// $link = mysqli_init();
// $success = mysqli_real_connect(
//    $link, 
//    $host, 
//    $user, 
//    $password, 
//    $db,
//    $port
// );

//$sql='SELECT * FROM users WHERE username ='.$_GET['username'];



$result = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username ="'.$_POST['username']).'"';
if(!$result){
    die($conn->error);  
}
$userids = array();

while ($row = $result->fetch_object()){
    $userids[] = $row->id;
}


echo $userids[0];

$conn->close();

?>
```

When we run this we get the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on string in /Users/brianleaf/Google Drive/htdocs/login.php:34 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /Users/brianleaf/Google Drive/htdocs/login.php on line 34
```

We are new to PHP so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `$result = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username ="'.$_POST['username']).'"';` Any reason why the `"` is being concatenated to the end there? The reason you're hitting that error is self-explanatory: `$result` is a string

Comment: @ShaneOH If we don't put it in "" it thinks that it is a column and not an value.

Comment: U need to check error for your query `if( !$result)
  die($mysql->error);`

Comment: The closing " of your query must be inside $conn->query, not outside, you may have an SQL error here. What do you get with this ? : `$result = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username ="'.$_POST['username'].'"');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have the quote on the outside of that last `)` on line 34 rather than on the inside.

Try, for example:

```
$sql='SELECT * FROM users WHERE username ="'.$_POST['username'].'"';
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

or

`$result = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username ="'.$_POST['username'].'"');`

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You've created a string. This is the way it should be:

```
$result = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username="' . $_POST['username'] . '"');
```